# Convert ASP.Net UI to React js components

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

I have ASP.Net application, we want to convert to React js. Is there any tool or library which converts from ASP.Net application to React js components??

We are trying to do manual conversion but lots of pages needs to be converted manually.. It is taking more time.. Is there any tool or library which converts from ASP.Net application to React js components??

Comment: Doubtfull. If you build a system based on 100's of assumutpions for one set of tools, then in most cases, you not going to automatic convert to another system. I mean, if you build some forms on the desktop for ms-access, then they not going to be automatic converted to web forms. Same case for you. Adopting a differing approach to some software means, well, a different approach. As noted, webforms applications are happy to accept, use and adopt react.js, or just about any of the new toolsets from bootstrap to jQuery etc. However, as such no automatic conversion exists or will occur for you.

Comment: TLDR: not possible